# What is one word to describe "i am feeling people are not listening/hearing me"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can i express the fact that i feel people are not hearing or acknowledging what i have to say?

I have already seen words such as the following (which i don't feel fits well): unheard, inaudible, voiceless.

Thank you,

Comment: How about: ***ignored***

Comment: You're being ignored, making you feel ***under-acclaimed***.

Comment: Perhaps you are feeling your ideas are being **under-valued**.

Answer (score 2):

I felt that "dismissed" may be more appropriate, from the lack of acknowledgement, this is a little stronger than ignored (in my view) as it shows disdain and contempt. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**persona non grata**  (Although that might be too harsh for what you are referencing.) 
Literally meaning an unwelcome or unacceptable person.

One who may quite likely be ignored or **ostracized** by others, or to be excluded or shunned.

Answer (score 0):

Since "I-messages" tend to get better results than anything that sounds like an accusation:

*I am not feeling listened to* (OR *heard*).

Answer (score 0):

Invisible, as in Invisible Man.

Or insignificant.  Minimized.  Overlooked.  Unseen.  Bypassed.  Denied.  Erased.